# Featured Content Slider ScrollTo

Tags: jquery

im trying to make **[Featured Content Slider](http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/featured-content-slider-using-jquery-ui/)** auto scroll its list item when they are highlighted. But when i tried the jquery code i did it dont even scroll the content. It would be better is someone might help me solve this problem out.

i tried,

JS:

```
var container = $("#featured ul");
scrollTo = $('ul li.ui-tabs-active.ui-state-active');        
container.animate({
    scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
});
```

with its actual code;

```
<div id="featured" >
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-1"><a href="#fragment-1"><img src="images/image1-small.jpg" alt="" /><span>15+ Excellent High Speed Photographs</span></a></li>
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-2"><a href="#fragment-2"><img src="images/image2-small.jpg" alt="" /><span>20 Beautiful Long Exposure Photographs</span></a></li>
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-3"><a href="#fragment-3"><img src="images/image3-small.jpg" alt="" /><span>35 Amazing Logo Designs</span></a></li>
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-4"><a href="#fragment-4"><img src="images/image4-small.jpg" alt="" /><span>Create a Vintage Photograph in Photoshop</span></a></li>
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-5"><a href="#fragment-5"><img src="images/image4-small.jpg" alt="" /><span>Create a Vintage Photograph in Photoshop</span></a></li>
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-6"><a href="#fragment-6"><img src="images/image4-small.jpg" alt="" /><span>Create a Vintage Photograph in Photoshop</span></a></li>
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-7"><a href="#fragment-7"><img src="images/image4-small.jpg" alt="" /><span>Create a Vintage Photograph in Photoshop</span></a></li>
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-8"><a href="#fragment-8"><img src="images/image4-small.jpg" alt="" /><span>Create a Vintage Photograph in Photoshop</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- First Content -->
    <div id="fragment-1" class="ui-tabs-panel" style="">
        <img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="info" >
            <h2><a href="#" >15+ Excellent High Speed Photographs</a></h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla tincidunt condimentum lacus. Pellentesque ut diam....<a href="#" >read more</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Second Content -->
    <div id="fragment-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" style="">
        <img src="images/image2.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="info" >
            <h2><a href="#" >20 Beautiful Long Exposure Photographs</a></h2>
            <p>Vestibulum leo quam, accumsan nec porttitor a, euismod ac tortor. Sed ipsum lorem, sagittis non egestas id, suscipit....<a href="#" >read more</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Third Content -->
    <div id="fragment-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" style="">
        <img src="images/image3.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="info" >
            <h2><a href="#" >35 Amazing Logo Designs</a></h2>
            <p>liquam erat volutpat. Proin id volutpat nisi. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur facilisis sollicitudin ornare....<a href="#" >read more</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Fourth Content -->
    <div id="fragment-4" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" style="">
        <img src="images/image4.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="info" >
            <h2><a href="#" >Create a Vintage Photograph in Photoshop</a></h2>
            <p>Quisque sed orci ut lacus viverra interdum ornare sed est. Donec porta, erat eu pretium luctus, leo augue sodales....<a href="#" >read more</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Fourth Content -->
    <div id="fragment-5" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" style="">
        <img src="images/image4.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="info" >
            <h2><a href="#" >Create a Vintage Photograph in Photoshop</a></h2>
            <p>Quisque sed orci ut lacus viverra interdum ornare sed est. Donec porta, erat eu pretium luctus, leo augue sodales....<a href="#" >read more</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Fourth Content -->
    <div id="fragment-6" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" style="">
        <img src="images/image4.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="info" >
            <h2><a href="#" >Create a Vintage Photograph in Photoshop</a></h2>
            <p>Quisque sed orci ut lacus viverra interdum ornare sed est. Donec porta, erat eu pretium luctus, leo augue sodales....<a href="#" >read more</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Fourth Content -->
    <div id="fragment-7" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" style="">
        <img src="images/image4.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="info" >
            <h2><a href="#" >Create a Vintage Photograph in Photoshop</a></h2>
            <p>Quisque sed orci ut lacus viverra interdum ornare sed est. Donec porta, erat eu pretium luctus, leo augue sodales....<a href="#" >read more</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Fourth Content -->
    <div id="fragment-8" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" style="">
        <img src="images/image4.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="info" >
            <h2><a href="#" >Create a Vintage Photograph in Photoshop</a></h2>
            <p>Quisque sed orci ut lacus viverra interdum ornare sed est. Donec porta, erat eu pretium luctus, leo augue sodales....<a href="#" >read more</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

imnot so gud at this but i tried putting up a jsfiddle-->http://jsfiddle.net/pS6Bh/

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: added fiddle,please check if correct

Comment: Did you mean, the auto-slide is not working?

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind it stopped autoscrolling is, Jquery Tabs rote function is depreciated in the latest version. To make it work, you should use [jQuery UI Tabs](https://github.com/cmcculloh/jQuery-UI-Tabs-Rotate) from Christopher McCulloh

Here is a **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/pS6Bh/1/)** by including that script

You should also include the following CSS

```
#featured li.ui-tabs-active{   
    background:url('images/selected-item.gif') top left no-repeat;    
}  
#featured ul.ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a{   
    background:#ccc;   
}
```

Comment: thank you bro, the auto-slide was also working in my side the thing is that when the active item reaches to its 5th or 6th item, it is not showing, because the scrol bar does not automatically scroll according to the active item. that is my problem :c